# Javascript detect Wireless settings

Tags: javascript, settings, wireless, detect

It is possible to detect the Wireless settings on a mobile device with pure HTML/JavaScript?

That is e.g. to check if a mobile device is (a) connected to a certain Wi-Fi and if (b) a given radius/certificate is enabled in the connectivity of the given network

?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The best you can do is to use http://www.w3.org/TR/netinfo-api/#idl-def-Connection where avaliable. Support is low, but it will help you decide what sort of connection the device has.

If you actually want geolocation, just ask for it directly using navigator.geolocation. (http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)